# Presenting ModalViewController Modally on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, modal-dialog, viewcontroller

Im calling this code from the MasterViewController in a UISplitVC for an iPad app:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
//PRESENT MODALVC
ModalViewController *modalVC = [[ModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalViewController" bundle:nil];
[self setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentModalViewController:modalVC animated:YES];
```

}

but it doesn't work.  No ModalVC appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
ModalViewController *modalVC = [[ModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalViewController" bundle:nil];
[modalVC setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen]; //You set the presentation style of the controller that would be presented, not the presenting controller
//This check is needed, because presentModalViewController:animated is depreciated in iOS5.0 and presentViewController:animated:completion must be used instead. The same is valid for dismissModalViewControllerAnimated and dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)])
    [self presentViewController:modalVC animated:YES completion:nil];
else
    [self presentModalViewController:modalVC animated:YES];
```

If you are targeting iOS5.0+ only this check is not needed and you should use only `presentViewController:animated:completion` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion`

Comment: Hello @Graver, I presented the modalView, it shows fine, now I press home button and again open the app, what happens is that while opening the app, it dismisses the modalView which I left open, how to prevent this

Comment: You must be doing it somewhere. Put breakpoints everywhere you call: `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`, or `dismissViewControllerAnimated` and debug to resolve.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726466/prevent-uimodalviewcontroller-from-dismissing-itself, Please check this @Graver